# Equation Options on Word 2011 for Mac

Tags: ms-office

I use both Macs and PCs. In the PC version of Word, I can modify the equation options directly from the Equation ribbon bar. One option I need is the ability to copy the equation as plain text. Does this option exist on the Mac Word 2011?

Comment: The ribbon shows an option to change from professional to linear.  The linear seems to copy to plain text.  Am I missing something here?  Perhaps you can edit your question with a screenshot showing what you are accustomed to with your PC?  Would love to be of assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a **very** old question, but here goes.  The option to change to linear allows for copying as plain text.  This option can be found in the **Equation** ribbon.  Also, the Equation box dropdown has the change option as well.

[image: Equation ribbon]

[image: Equation Dropdown]